# Bootbox - Center Text on Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I'm using Bootbox to create a nicer looking alert dialog for my web application. Is it possible to center-justify the text on the alert dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just add this style to your css:

```
.modal-body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3YMay/)**